# Appending a list of lists to a list, and clearing the original list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a `for` loop that appends lists to a list, and then appends that list to another list, giving a list of list of lists as follows:

```
list_1 = [1,2]
list_2 = [3,4,765]
list_3 = [0.3,-2.32]

list_of_lists = []
list_of_lists.append(list_1)
list_of_lists.append(list_2)
list_of_lists.append(list_3)

list_of_list_of_lists = []
list_of_list_of_lists.append(list_of_lists)
```

I then try and clear the `list_of_lists` variable with,

```
list_of_lists.clear()
```

but unfortunately this clears `list_of_lists` from `list_of_list_of_lists` too. Is there any way to clear `list_of_lists` itself, but keep everything in `list_of_list_of_lists` intact?

Comment: `list_of_list_of_lists.append(list_of_lists.copy())`

Comment: Or `list_of_lists = []`, if it's not used anywhere else up to this point. BTW, your second block of code can be written as `list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll use the ' list_of_lists.clear() ' at the end of your script it wont be empty and you can reuse it.

For example :

```
list_1 = [1,2]
list_2 = [3,4,765]
list_3 = [0.3,-2.32]

list_of_lists = [list_1 , list_2 , list_3]

list_of_list_of_lists = [list_of_lists.copy()]

print(list_of_list_of_lists)
# or do whatever you need to do 

list_of_lists.clear()

list_of_list_of_lists.append('just_test')

print(list_of_list_of_lists)
```

The output will be :

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4, 765], [0.3, -2.32]]]
[[[1, 2], [3, 4, 765], [0.3, -2.32]], 'just_test']
```